# Unresolved external symbol in a class function

Tags: c++

can anyone tell me what is the problem with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Exception
{
    string err;
public:
    Exception (string _err) : err(_err) {}
    const string& Err ();
};

int main()
{
    Exception exc("error");
    cout << exc.Err() << endl;
}
```

I get unresolved external symbol error on call to the function Exception::Err.

EDIT: Now I see what's the problem, I'm sorry for asking such a stupid question. But I really did spent half an hour looking at the code trying to figure out what's wrong.
Might aswell delete the question to save me from bad reputation. :D  And you guys from a bad read. ;)

Comment: Where did you implement `const string& Err ();`??

Comment: where's the body of `Exception::Err`?

Comment: FYI, there is a an object `std::exception` already existing.  This is one case where you may not want to have `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Good thing the OP named the class `Exception` instead of `exception`.

Comment: Your `main` function lies.  You declared it to return `int` but there is no `return` statement.

Comment: You should really read up on [`std::exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) and the [`what()` method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It's a well known fact that the `return` statement can be omitted from `main()` and conforms to the c++ standard.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews _"You should really read up ..."_ Without seeing `throw`, `try` or `catch`, I can't see how that would be relevant.

Comment: Now I see what's the problem, I'm sorry for asking such a stupid question. But I really did spent half an hour looking at the code trying to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The error means you didn't define one of your member functions. In this case, you don't have a function body for  `const string& Err ();`

Comment: We actually don't need to answer these basic questions over and over again.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Yes, they should be answered so people can increase their reputation points. :-)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Sure this action will increase rep actually?

Comment: Now I see what's the problem, I'm sorry for asking such a stupid question. But I really did spent half an hour looking at the code trying to figure out what's wrong.